# How to allow Bootstrap relative responsive img height when using object-fit:cover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I can make an image height scale up and down relative to the Bootstrap 5 responsive window width?

This `article .card` contains the lead photo for an article...

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/alexander-dummer-UH-xs-FizTk-unsplash-1.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body px-4 px-md-5 py-md-4">
        <!-- Body stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Source photo will always be irregularly shaped for the space. Therefore, I am using `object-fit: cover;` and `height: 20em;`

```
/* Uniform image */
article .card-img-top {
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20em;
}
```

Trouble is, whilst `20em;` is about right at `lg` width, it stays the same height on all lower widths, making it too tall for those widths. **As the width steps down from `lg` to `md`, `sm` and `xs`, the image should get shorter and shorter, too, always having the dimensions of a letterbox**.

How can I scale the height as well as the width in this scenario?

Do I need to resort to hand-coding media queries that match Bootstrap 5's, or is there something else I can do?

[image]

```css
/**
 * ==============================================================================
 *                       ARTICLE
 * ==============================================================================
 */

/* Uniform image */
article .card-img-top {
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20em;
}

/* Bolder headings */
.h1,
h1,
.h3,
h3 {
  font-weight: 800 !important;
}

/* Bigger HQ */
.h1,
h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.675rem + 1.5vw) !important;
}

/* More H3 spacing */
.h3,
h3 {
  margin-top: 2.5rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em !important;
}

/* Bigger article text size */
.entry-content p,
.entry-content li {
  font-size: 1.12rem;
}

/* On-brand hyperlinks */
.entry-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration-color: orange;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.125em;
  text-underline-offset: 1.5px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

/* More line space for .lh-lg */
.lh-lg {
  line-height: 1.7 !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Families have changed and brands must keep up &#8211; The Map</title>
<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='BootstrapCSS-css'  href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' media='' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='BootstrapIcons-css'  href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css' media='' />
</head>

<body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-270 single-format-standard logged-in wp-embed-responsive bg-light">

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white border-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iiGpDdR.png" alt="" height="36" class="ms-2">
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="page-wrapper">

    <div class="container-fluid p-0 mx-0 p-md-2 p-lg-3">

        <div class="row mx-0 px-0">

<aside class="col-1 d-none d-md-block"></aside>


<main class="col-12 col-md-11 col-lg-8 px-0">
    <article id="post-270" class="post-270 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476703993599-0035a21b17a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2970&q=80" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body px-4 px-md-5 py-md-4">
                <header class="entry-header alignwide">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">Families have changed and brands must keep up</h1>                    <div id="entry-topics" class="pt-2 pb-3">
                        <span class="badge bg-danger">Danger</span>
                        <span class="badge bg-warning text-dark">Warning</span>
                        <span class="badge bg-info text-dark">Info</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="entry-author" class="pt-3 pb-3 d-flex border-0 align-items-center">
                        <img alt="" src="http://localhost:8888/themap/wp-content/uploads/users/avatars/verrabudimlija-150x150.jpg" class="flex-shrink-0 me-2 rounded-circle img-fluid avatar avatar-50" height="50" width="50"/>                        <!--<img src="https://newsroom.mastercard.com/asia-pacific/files/2020/06/rajamannar_raja-200x200.jpg"
                            class="flex-shrink-0 me-2 rounded-circle" style="width:50px;height:50px;">-->
                        <div>
                            <strong>Verra Budimlija</strong><br>
                            <img src="http://localhost:8888/themap/wp-content/uploads/companies/favicons/favicons-1-1.png" alt="Favicon for Wavemaker" width="16">                            <small class="text-secondary">
                                Chief strategy officer, Wavemaker UK                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                <div class="entry-content pt-3">
                    <p class="lh-lg">Over the last two years, the COVID-19 pandemic up-ended family life.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<h3>Key findings</h3>
<ul>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
</ul>
<p class="lh-lg">How brands get to become that navigator is fascinating.</p>
<h3>Reconnecting with family</h3>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">In other words, campaigns, like families themselves, must be a jigsaw.</p>
<h3>Multi-channel life</h3>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>

<aside class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
            content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
</div></aside>



        </div><!-- end .row -->

    </div><!-- end .container-fluid -->

</div><!-- end .#page-wrapper -->

<footer class="bg-dark text-light text-center">
    Footer
</footer>


<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' id='BootstrapJSBundle-js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet (including bootstrap) so we get a bit of the context?

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the class `h-100` on the image tag.

Comment: That seems to make the image 100% of the _image_ size, making it too tall at any width.